# How do I request a Stack Overflow user to answer my question?

Tags: discussion

I know there are some Stack Overflow experts who can answer my question. So how do I get their attention?

I see *"Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this"*, but I don't know the users' Twitter or email addresses.

Comment: Please don't. Answerers have their own right to choose which question they want to answer. Even if you (anyhow) ask them to answer, they have their right to reject.

Comment: @AndrewT. I totally agree and updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I am happy to provide an email address for such messages.  OK, it will point at a black hole, but I kinda like the idea of wasting the time of anyone who thinks this is a good idea.

Comment: folks are really angry at this question, but to be fair, i need my life outside SO. Dont tag me in your problems.

Answer (score 47):

### You don't.

You just post a question and see who answers it.

If you really want to, you *could* link to the question in one of SO's [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), provided the specific room's rules allow that.

Also, if the user you need is online on chat, you *could* create a room with him, but generally, that's **not appreciated**.

Answer (score 27):

1. Write a good question. If it gets many upvotes, more people will read it and possibly answer it.
2. Offer a bounty - the question is then guaranteed to get more attraction.
3. Be patient - if you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603031/how-to-create-complex-net-objects-from-jsonjavascript-in-asp-net-webapi-using), the users from America are still asleep and haven't had a chance to read it.

Answer (score 18):

People have a right to live without SO. The high rep users who do share their email details are usually specific about when and how to go about contacting them.

Personally, I think it's considerate to not chase people around the internet and keep the SO activities here (my opinion).

Or you can research and find which high rep users have services where you can ping them.

[Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) has a yearly subscription to his book and access to other services with that. The service includes a SO ping, where you can ping questions for him to look at, but this falls within a set of conditions to avoid abuse. *Now I stumbled upon this by researching Android resources, not from SO.*

I have found this useful, but I **pay** for this service and use it sparingly, as I appreciate he is a human being and as far as I know, has no clones.

I'd love to ping [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) and [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in on all my posts for feedback.. but I suspect they may also be uncloned.... :/

Having said this on two or three occasions (literally) I have pinged a user I have crossed paths with and asked them to look at something, and I thank them profusely for their feedback. But this is only after I've had some interaction with them, and not the extremely high level users. I won't tell you how I go about doing this, as I don't want to encourage anyone else to do it. ;)

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot. There is nowhere for you to enter a name.

That said, I think the SO text is misleading and I don't blame the OP. If I know someone off SO that can answer the question, I won't post it here. So the "know someone who can answer" definitely means someone on SO and there should be a box I can enter a username. Otherwise, I suggest the text to be updated to something like "Share a link to ... so more people can see".

Answer (score -3):

No you cannot ask or force someone to answer your question on stackoverflow.People with knowledge in particular area will answer you if they want to answer.Ask a good question.if you get upvotes people will reply you.