# How can I contact a user or respond to an edit rejection?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

Is it possible to respond to rejected edits? I fixed a bug with a C# answer: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26617475.

One rejection advised me to reach out to the author of the answer, which I wasn't able to do on Stack Overflow (even on chat) -- perhaps because my reputation was too low. Another rejection stated that my edit "deviates from the original intent of the post" -- which is absolutely incorrect, as the original code threw away the email display names after setting them.

At this point, it looks like I've lost the ability to edit the answer further, and I don't see any way to respond to the rejection messages. Is there something I'm missing? Is it possible for me to reach out to these users or respond in any way?

Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate of [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). I'm not asking if the edit was good; it fixes a bug with the answer and more closely honors the intention of the author.

Comment: When they said to contact the author, I assume they meant via comment which you do have enough reputation for.

Comment: You can't. If an answer is wrong, see it as an opportunity to post a _better_ answer if your edit was rejected. Or leave a comment pointing out the error in the code.

Comment: A moderator should consider sending a message to the user who approved the edit...

Comment: The answer wasn't wrong, per se -- it just had a unintentional bug. I did end up commenting, and am hoping the original author will update the answer. But not being able to respond to the rejection directly seems very strange.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The edit was good. I don't mean to sound disrespectful, but anyone who understands C#/MailMessage will be able to see that. But my question is not about the correctness of the edit.

Comment: @HereticMonkey https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews

Comment: @pppery Am I supposed to report these kinds of things there?

Comment: The edit was not good. You should not be editing code to correct mistakes. I know C# and `MailMessage` just fine, but I wouldn't edit the code. I would comment on the answer to bring the errors that would come up due to that code up with the answerer, giving them a chance to edit it themselves. If they chose not to edit, I'd add an answer, giving credit to the original answer, with the corrected code. The rejection was correct.

Comment: I was saying that there was a chat room for reporting incorrect reviews, not making any kind of judgement on whether this specific review merits a report there.

Comment: @HereticMonkey According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit, you can edit "to correct minor mistakes". The bug in the code was just a small part of the overall answer. To me, as a more rookie stackoverflow user, it seemed simplest to just correct the bug and move on.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed the code.

Comment: Honestly I'm inclined to think this is a good edit not a bad edit.  *Clearly conflicts with the author's intent* is a bit of a judgement call and in this case I would say it does not.  As far as adding another answer, I suspect the reality is that most stack overflow visitors just copypasta the top-rated answer and never scroll down to see the corrections, and maybe never notice they have a bug until much later.  So I might have approved this.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I would not report the review as bad.  Even if if you don't agree with the review, *Clearly conflicts with the author's intent* is a bit of a judgement call.  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews should be used for blatantly bad reviews like approving a non-English post or a post with only screenshots of code in Triage or First Posts (which I see pretty often).

Comment: @RobertHarvey (and dbc) Thanks, guys. My brain is still spinning from all of this -- from quick downvotes, to arguments against my edit, all from users with a lot of reputation. Even though I love Stack Overflow, I clearly have a lot to learn when it comes to the meta. I guess the answer to my posted question here is that there's no way to respond to users or rejected edits. If someone wants to write that in an answer here, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Life gets a lot better once you have 2000 rep and can make edits unilaterally.  Now if only Stack Exchange would fix the editing system so that, as a privileged editor, I could bypass a suggested edit without being placed into the same edit approval queue as everyone else.

Comment: Only speculating here, but you might have gotten downvotes because your question title sounds a little like [How do I request a Stack Overflow user to answer my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309690), to which the answer is **You don't**.  (Stack overflow doesn't have a general messaging facility which is very much appreciated by many higher-rep posters here.)  A title like *What should I do after a minor code fix to an answer was rejected as being too major* might have gone over better.

Comment: Another possibility is that people downvoted the post because they disagreed with the premise (or, in other words, think the edit should have been rejected)-- I downvoted this for that reason.

Comment: @pppery can you please expand on this for my benefit? I couldn't find any way to contact the user (as suggested by an editor) in the UI, so I asked the community. What was the premise that you disagreed with? Edit: looks like you updated this to clarify what you meant -- thank you.

Comment: That the edit you made should have been approved.

Comment: @pppery Okay, thank you. I do think users should feel free to upvote/downvote as they please. Since my question only tangentially dealt with the correctness of my edit, I don't agree with the downvote -- but I respect your right to make it, and I appreciate you clarifying the reason.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can dream. As for your wish, more clicks means more job security! ...or something.

Comment: The issue was not necessarily with your edit, but a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/500833) edit which _added_ that even though there are overloads for MailMessage that take either string, string, _or_, MailAddress, MailAddress... That send, senders won't necessarily have domain knowledge, so if making code edits it can sometimes be helpful to leave a link to relevant documentation (or any other previous bad edits) in your edit summary

Comment: @Nick Oh wow, good catch. So the original answer was correct, then someone added the bug in an edit. Surprising.

Comment: Hi @KevinMeboe - I was one of the reviewers (literally chanced on this Q&A) and rejected on a premise that if an author is still active on the site, it is more respectful to ping them in a comment a move on. Once you have 2K rep, you can go guns blazing, but I wouldn't recommend that either. Before that, when you reach 1e2 rep, you can open a chat room (and on 1K - private ones). Unfortunately, the review comment section is very limited, so the wording may have confused you. The second review probably had the same reasoning, but chose a canned decline reason instead

Comment: @OlegValter That makes sense, and I'll be doing that from now on. This was a bit of a unique case where the code was incorrect as written, and was actively going against what the author was trying to do.

Comment: @KevinMeboe - thank you for replying. I am usually torn on reviewing such edits, this guideline helps avoid ambiguity in decisions on rejecting / approving such edits - if the due process was followed (i.e., the OP did not log in for a couple of months or did not respond), you can go ahead. Oh, and another thing: you can take such edits to one the public chat rooms if you are unsure.

Answer (score -4):

> ...and more closely honors the intention of the author.

I have a feeling you don't understand the meaning of *Clearly conflicts with the author's intent* in Stack OverFlow. Because looking at the original post, and your edit:

Before: `MailMessage mmsg = new MailMessage(maFrom.Address, maTo.Address);`

After:   `MailMessage mmsg = new MailMessage(maFrom, maTo);`

**Do you think that the two `.Adress` were intentional, or were they typos? 
Clearly they were intentional, whether the code is accurate or not.**

In situations like this, you have plenty of options: 1. Comment, 2. Downvote, 3. Post another answer.

Comment: I assumed they were a relic that remained as the code was developed. Regardless, editing to remove the bug seemed to be the correct choice, especially since it didn't change the spirit of the answer (other than to fix the obvious error).

Comment: I can understand this point of view for a **question**. But fixing simple bugs and typos in **answers**? That's entirely fine. We want more good content.