# What to do if a poster adds a username in the title for directing their question to a specific user?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

How to handle a situation where a new user to the site posts a question, wants to direct that question to a specific user (the highest-ranked user for that specific tag), and so the poster adds the high-scoring user's name in their question's title.

Do I

- Ignore it?
- Edit it out?
- Flag it for moderation?

Note that I did search for similar meta questions but could not come up with one. I did find these:

- [How do I request a Stack Overflow user to answer my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309690/how-do-i-request-a-stack-overflow-user-to-answer-my-question)
- [Routing question to particular Stack Exchange user or users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-question-to-particular-stack-exchange-user-or-users)

Both with diametrically opposed accepted and highly up-voted answers. Go figure.

Comment: Is the username vital to the problem in question at hand? My guess is 99% of the time it is not, so it should be dealt with as any other meta information - edited out on sight (unless you can't be bothered to do so, in which case - carry on :))

Comment: @OlegValter: thanks for your reply. No, the username is of interest to the OP, since they want to attract that highly ranked user to their question. The user has no relevance to the problem itself, such as could happen if the high-ranked user answered a similar question from the OP previously.

Comment: Re: title - NP, I tried to clarify to avoid it being considered as *your* request - feel free to override as necessary. Re: relevance - I'd say it's meta info then - and we deal with meta info by editing it out last time I checked :) Don't see why a username should be different. That would also go against the "focus on content not people" paradigm.

Comment: How would I handle a question directed at a specific user, I would edit the title of the question, to match what is considered to be an acceptable question title.  If the question itself was poor by itself, I would likely vote to close as it's likely not clear and downvote it.

Comment: OK, I think that most would edit the name out, which is what I will do forthwith. Thank you for your time and attention

Comment: The answer by Jon Skeet on the linked MSE post is from '09. It's *possible* Jon's changed their mind on this topic since then.

Comment: Aha, I found the question.

Comment: This seems to have much the same motivation as adding "**Urgent!**", "**Very important!**", or "**Please help!!!!!**" to a title, and would be just as inappropriate.  Also, making it clear right in the title that there's one user's input that they value above all others seems like it could be counter-productive.

Comment: What people don't seem to add is that you should leave a friendly comment telling the user that they shouldn't do this, and that the targeted user won't see it anyway. We can assume good faith and they'll stop doing this. Silently removing this fluff from the title will make repeat offense more likely.

Comment: @Lance FAQ on that: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](/q/326569/4518341)

Comment: "Both with diametrically opposed accepted and highly up-voted answers." Sure. But the question at -8, with the answer suggesting it should be allowed, is a) from 2009; b) proposing built-in support rather than talking about whether to do it manually; c) answered by notorious Stack Overflow workaholic Jon Skeet; d) who knew even then that he was bucking the trend. The question at -42 is unequivocal, the answer is supported by everyone else, and it's based in fundamental site principles (i.e. this is *not a discussion forum*).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Agreed. My general template is: `Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. As such, please do not XYZ. We are generally not interested in ABC; we are interested in **the code**.`

Comment: "Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi! You're my only hope!" Effective and appropriate if you put it in a message you send specifically to one person (delivery by droid optional but recommended), not as much when you put it in a question on SO.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**Edit it out**. SO is about content, not people, so if a person isn't directly related to the topic of a question, mentioning them is [noise, which should be removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/4518341).

I'd also leave a comment to the effect of,

> I removed the mention of a particular user. Instead, focus on writing a good question and using the right tags, which will attract more skilled eyes, possibly including the person you mentioned.

which is similar to [what Glorfindel answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309692/4518341) on the MSO question you linked.

Comment: Key - _"SO is about content, not people"_

Comment: I think I'd add a single caveat which is to ensure that the username is not providing attribution. For example, a follow-up question for a particular user: "Can @so-and-so help me implement their \[answer\] to my previous question \[Some Question\]?" This case may need edited to be an attribution rather than being edited out entirely.

Comment: @HenryEcker: That attribution should be in the post body by adding a link to the relevant answer, not in the title. In the title, it's an attempt to ping a specific user and should be edited out.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree. By the @ "may need edited to be an attribution rather than being edited out entirely." I did actually mean make an edit which meets attribution requirements including a link to the answer and to the username as required by [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). I was not differentiating a title-only edit vs an edit of the post.

Comment: _"SO is about content, not people"_ which is why my content writes itself on SO using my account

Comment: @galdin Sorry, are you being facetious? I can't tell. Of course SO is **by** people, but I'm saying it's not **about** people.

Comment: @wjandrea I agree with your answer as a whole, but not with that statement. SO is about people, content is only _how_ contributors serve people. Should fluff be edited out? Absolutely. But that is because it IS about people. We care about the content because of people :)

Comment: @galdin I think you're using "about" differently, maybe to mean the purpose? I'm using it to mean the topic. Anyway, I didn't coin that maxim; it's been around [at least 11 years in the context of voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/343832), and it's enshrined in the [Code of Conduct](/conduct) ("Focus on the content, not the person").

Comment: @wjandrea oh yes, we vote on the content, not for who posted the content. But the content exists to serve people. The line you quoted from the CoC also exists for people. (**No name-calling or personal attacks.** Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”).) The fact that we're having this conversation in a way proves that we do care about the people and hope our efforts on SO helps others. SO is about people.; content is just the how.

Comment: @galdin OK, yeah, you're using "about" to mean purpose, not topic.